# Design options for recursive sum/product type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type:
"A general algebraic data type is a possibly recursive sum type of product types."

I'm looking to create a *first class* representation of algebraic data types in Haskell, i.e. to represent (recursive) products and disjoint unions in a manner that can be pattern-matched against.

Concretely, I'd like to be able to express, in a typesafe manner, a recursive datatype which has:

- Literals
- Sums
- Products

Edit:
In response to a comment asking for an explicit definition, then expressed in terms of fixed-point equations, I believe this is therefore the type:

Edit2: updated further according to comments under answer by @Noughtmare

```
[X,Y] = X {- Literal -} + ( X + Y ) {- Sum -} + ( X * Y ) {- Product -}
```

2. I'd like to be able to define (or preferably even derive) a functor instance for it, and preferably a monad instance.

One option for typesafety is to use GADTs. However, it's not then clear how to derive a functor instance (or indeed, whether even manually defining one is possible).

What are the design options here?

EDIT: People don't seem to care much for the fixpoint equation, so in an attempt to be concrete, here's a GADT formulation (but bear in mind that an *assumption* that GADTs is the way to go, begs the question):

```
data X a where
    Lit :: a -> X a 
    Sum :: Either (X a) (X b) -> X (Either a b)
    Product :: (X a,X b) -> X (a, b)
```

Comment: What do you mean by Sums and Products? Do you want to build AST of types (for a compiler I guess)?

Comment: @Abastro I'm referring to the traditional use of these terms: 'sum types' and 'product types', i.e. the recursive data type is closed under sums and products.

Comment: Closed under sums/products? What do you mean here by "closure"? You can make new type using sum type or product type, but I do not think that would make some kind of "closure".

Comment: Let the datatype be X a. By 'closure under sums and products', I mean that (something isomorphic to)
Either (X a) (X b) and (X a, X b) are also 'types of X'. Not to be confused with the notion of 'lexical closure' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: Can you show the GADT that you have in mind? I'm having a hard time understanding what you really want.

Comment: Oh, so you want `Either (X a) (X b) ~ X c` and `(X a, X b) ~ X d` for some `c` and `d`?

Comment: *Recursive* data types can't be defined with just sums and products; you need fixed points as well. (Haskell syntax just allows for the fixed point to be generated automatically when the same type constructor appears on the left and right side of the definition.) Closure is a property of algebraic data types in general, not one particular type. ADTs are closed under sum because the sum of two ADTs is also an ADT; the product of two ADTs is also an ADT, and the fixed point of an ADT (if it has one) is an ADT.

Comment: @Noughtmare Well, choosing a *specific* form begs the question of whether functor can be defined on it. I'll add an edit defining it in terms of fixedpoint equations.

Comment: @Abastro Together with Lit a, yes.

Comment: The way you're trying to explain what you want doesn't seem to be working out well. Maybe you should back up a step and walk us down the garden path. What is the top-level program you want to write? Why do you believe that the best way to write that program is to have a data type like this (whatever "this" is)? What alternatives have you considered and rejected?

Comment: @DanielWagner Context and further clarification added.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the already-existing [GHC.Generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html).

Comment: What about your GADT is not suitable? What problem are we trying to fix?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, your equation can be translated quite literally into Haskell:

```
data A x y = Lit x | SumL x | SumR y | Prod x y deriving Functor
```

Now as you noted a `Bifunctor` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the product type to be of the form Prod (X a) (X b) which was why I was thinking that GADTs might be required. Unless I'm missing something, similarly for the Sum part (in the manner of data Either a b = Left a | Right b).

Comment: @NietzscheanAI but then what is the functor supposed to do? For example look at the instances for products and sums in Haskell, they just ignore one of the type variables. If you define a structure that is closed over products and sums, then which variables should be ignored? You can only pick one for your functor instance.

Comment: Thanks. So X will need to be parameterized by two type variables a and b, say (which is why my recurrence equations looked screwy - will edit). 

Hence (by analogy with Either a b), looks like a functor instance can only be defined for X a, and X a b will require a bifunctor.

Comment: @NietzscheanAI do note that you now no longer have a closure, it is now just a single layer. And the literal seems to be redundant because that is just he left case of the sum. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: bear in mind that the equation I give in the question is a *recurrence*, by analogy with the equation for List: X = 1 + X, where 1 == Nil and X == Cons.

Hence, I do indeed want things to be closed.

Comment: Oh, I thought your `[X,Y]` notation was a constructor `[ _ , _ ]` with type variable arguments `X` and `Y`, but now I see that is probably not what you meant. Can you explain what `[X,Y]` means then?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the standard notation, but the intention is to convey that the fixpoint equation is parametric in two variables rather than just one.

Comment: Which variable do you want to fix over? Or you really want what I said earlier:
`Either (X a) (X b) ~ X c`, `(X a, X b) ~ X d`, `Lit a ~ X e`? In this case, `X = Identity` could suffice. (Applies for `Either a b = c`, `(a, b) = d`, `Lit a = e`)

Comment: This isn't recursive, and seems to treat `x` specially as you can have `x`-type literals but not `y`-type literals. Wouldn't `data A x = Lit x | SumL (A x) | SumR (A x) | Prod (A x) (A x)` be more appropriate?

Comment: @chepner that's literally what I had earlier see the revisions and see the first comment on this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that comment makes any sense. Since he mentioned GADTs, I wonder if the type itself  should even *be* parameterized, instead having multiple type-distinct literal constructers, all of which produce values of a single type. E.g. `data A where CharLit :: Char -> A; IntLit :: Int -> A; Sum :: A -> A -> A; Prod :: A -> A -> A;`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, but I don't want to lose parametricity. Since people seem to want a concrete example, I've added an explicit GADT description, but that does beg the question of whether GADTs are what is required.